# From Robot framework file to Azure priority column of test report

Tags: report, robotframework, meta-tags

[image]

Azure test results has a column called 'Priority'

In the Robot framework (.robot) files I have I'd like to use a metadata tag to pass to the report so that it shows up in the Azure pipeline results.

How can I do that? How should the format look like?

[The location in the file is here](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#free-test-suite-metadata)

[Publish test results Azure](http://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/test/publish-test-results?view=azure-devops&tabs=trx%2Cyaml)
( Priority  /TestRun/TestDefinitions/UnitTest.Attributes["priority"].Value )
( read on 50% of the page )